# PYTHONPATH works in interactive mode but fails in script

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

### Problem

I've been trying to run a python script which imports from the `Foundation` package:

`from Foundation import ...`

Whenever I try to run this I get the following error:
[image: Terminal output]

### Things I've done:

I've installed the `Foundation` package and verified that it was installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

I've added `export PYTHONPATH='/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` to my .zshrc file.

When I go into interactive mode, `sys.path` includes `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and I can successfully import Foundation:

[image]

When I run the script using `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`, `sys.path` does not include `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and importing Foundation fails:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening and/or how to fix this? Why does running this script have a different `sys.path` than running the same python executable in interactive mode?

(I know I could use `sys.path.extend(desired path)` or something like that but that's not an ideal solution)

Comment: You didn't mention that you're running it with `sudo`.  That gets you a different .zshrc; you don't inherit the environment.

Comment: You're running the script using `sudo`. It strips out most environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you run Python as your user (say `~joe` or whatever your UID is) but then you bring `sudo` to the table. And that's where things starts to differ, because it will not inherit your environment. Simple test for you to replay (substitute `python3` by whatever path/version you want):

```bash
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', 
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', 
'/home/<USER>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

then the same but with `sudo`:

```bash
$ sudo python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', 
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
```

To work this around you either need to ensure your superuser's environment fits your needs or you feed python interpreter with needed value of `PYTHONPATH` on the fly:

```bash
$ sudo PYTHONPATH=/FOO/BAR python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/FOO/BAR', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', 
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
```

Comment: This had me stuck for so long. Thanks for the help! I had no idea that sudo circumvented the `.zshrc` file.